# Installed second hard drive in computer and get BSOD with stop 0x00007b

Tags: windows, hard-drive, troubleshooting, sata, bsod

I have a computer with a Intel [DH55HC](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000023739/boards-and-kits/desktop-boards.html) motherboard.
It has eSata on the MB ports that work with SATA drives.

Anyway I installed a second 1 TB drive and reset the boot order. Windows starts and gets a BSOD with the stop code `INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE` (`0x0000007B` or simply `0x7b`).
When I removed the second hard drive the system worked again.

The second HDD has one ext3 partition that will be erased and Windows is on the first HDD.

Comment: Try switching the ports they're connected to.

Comment: @David Schwartz I will try that later today and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the system set up so that the SATA configuration was like this.

FC = First Controller

SC = Second Controller

First Hard Drive SC

Second Hard Drive FC

DVD Drive SC

I moved both hard drives to the first controller and left the DVD drive alone and that stopped the BSOD.

Unrelated to this but the second drive has to be RMA'd over another problem.

Answer (score 0):

The SATA port connection matters here. This is more generalized answer:

This BSOD is thrown when **the defective drive is connected to the first controller**.

The solution is to keep only functional drive(s) connected to the first controller. (Typically ports labeled `SATA0`, `SATA1`.) There can be more than one drive connected, but each of them must be in working condition.
The failing drive has to be connected to the second controller (Typically `SATA2`, `SATA3`, `SATA4`, `SATA5` – when in doubt, refer to documentation of your motherboard on how exactly the ports are assigned to controllers in your case.) Under such circumstances the computer is likely to boot normally, without going to the BSOD with error `0x7b`.